# useContext across files causes circular dependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-context

I have a two components Parent and Child and I want to export a context from Parent to Child but this causes circular dependency.

Consider, for example, Parent.js to be

```js
import {Child} from './Child.js';

export const MyContext = React.createContext();

const Parent = () => {
    return <MyContext.Provider><Child /></MyContext.Provider>;
}
```

and Child.js as

```js
import {MyContext} from 'Parent';

const Child = () => {
    const myContext = useContext(MyContext);
    return <>{myContext}</>;
}
```

I can pass this as props but if there are multiple level of nesting, it would be difficult. A possible solution I can think of is using another file called `contexts.js` and have all my contexts exported from there.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put your context in it's own file, .e.g `Context.js`. Then both `Parent.js` and `Child.js` can import it.

Comment: Yeah that's what I came up with as I mentioned. I was just looking if there is a better way developers usually use as this probably seems to be a case many people should have encountered.

Comment: Chatted with coworkers - This seems to be the best solution!

Answer (score 2):

Typically, rather than making the child a dependency of the parent, you loosely couple your context provider component from its children by making use of [`props.children`](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#propschildren).

`Parent.js`:

```js
export const MyContext = React.createContext();

const Parent = ({ children }) => {
    return <MyContext.Provider>{children}</MyContext.Provider>;
};

export default Parent;
```

`Child.js`:

```js
import { MyContext } from './Parent';

const Child = () => {
    const myContext = useContext(MyContext);
    return <>{myContext}</>;
};

export default Child;
```

Then you populate `props.children` with `<Child />` when you create your virtual DOM:

```js
import Parent from './Parent';
import Child from './Child';

const App = () => {
    return <Parent><Child /></Parent>;
};

...
```

Comment: This only works in simple cases. You can't expect literally every component to be placed into App?

Comment: @pbuzz007 you're being a bit literal, it's just the simplest example I can provide. `<Child />` can be deeply nested JSX anywhere inside `<Parent>...</Parent>`, which means any number of components can exist between them. And no, `Parent` doesn't have to go in `App` either.